# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in

Tags: php, laravel, parsing

I am uploading Laravel website without database. On my localhost everything is fine, but when I try to upload it on live server and run the URL, it shows a parse error:

[image: Parse error]

I have changed index.php something like that

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

My public folder files and other contents are in public_html dir. I have tried many times, but still not remove error.

Comment: Please paste your error as text, then we can read it more easily. Plain text does not need to be shown as a picture. This is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask already. Thanks.

Comment: Also please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) Bear in mind that people are giving up their free time here to help.

Comment: Anyway, the code you've shown doesn't reproduce the error. We'll probably need to see more of the relevant code. The error says the problem comes from "functions.php", yet you're saying you're showing us some lines from "index.php". It's unclear how you think those lines will be relevant? If you want us to help you fix the syntax error then you need to show us the code which causes it.

Comment: P.S. if you have this working in one machine, but not in another machine, then please check that a) both machines are running the same version of PHP, and b) on the live server you have uploaded all of the necessary files to the correct location and with the correct file permissions for the webserver to read them.

Comment: Why would you modify your `index.php`? please follow the install instructions and use the `public` folder as your root folder

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1: wrong installation**

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#configuration):

> Public Directory
>
> After installing Laravel, you should configure your web server's document / web root to be the public directory. The index.php in this directory serves as the front controller for all HTTP requests entering your application.

You need to serve your application under the `public` directory and **NOT** modify your `index.php`

**Problem 2: wrong PHP version**

The ?ResponseInterface is telling the PHP compiler the return from this function could be a nullable ReponseInterface object.
This feature was however introduced in `PHP 7.1`. So in order to remove this error message you have to upgrade to `PHP7.1` or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP version is below 7.1. Ramsey UUID version you are using (probably 4/master) requires php 7.2

Comment: the ? It is available in PHP 7.1 - most likely OP is running 5.6. But overall the package indeed required 7.2

Comment: what i do now?? please guide me

Comment: Update php version on your live server to 7.1 or up. If you are using shared hosting check their documentation how to. If you are using VPS check how to depending on your OS